# How to overload cin and use getline

Tags: c++

I am trying to finish my lab, however I don't know how to allocate memory to a string. So I keep getting the error 
`warning: ‘_name’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`

I don't also understand if my `getline` line is correct.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Grade& RO){
    int _mark;
    char* _name;

    std::cout<<"Subject name: ";
    is.ignore();
    is.getline(_name, (strlen(_name) + 1));

    std::cout<<"Mark :";
    is>> _mark;

    RO=Grade(_name, _mark);
return is;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::string`, not `char*`.

Comment: And pay more attention in class.

Comment: Change `_name` to `std::string`, and use `std::getline()` instead of `is.getline()`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok @Jessica, (to general question and few info) I guess,

`Grade` is a class with two data members: `int mark` and `string name`. And you want to overload the *insertion operator* `>>` to populate these values. 
(I recommend you leave all the `cout` expression outside this function).
 Here is one possible implementation:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& is, Grade& RO){
    // declare local variables to insert the input values
    int mark;
    string name;
    // extract values from input stream 
    is >> mark >> name;
    // assuming you have member functions that set values for the object RO
    RO.set_mark(mark);
    RO.set_name(name);

return is;
}
```